# d3.js not reading my JSON data from PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, json, d3.js

I am using a simple d3.js line graph to display data from a MySQL database. It was working fine when I was pulling data from a static CSV, but now that I'm trying to connect it to the database the graph is not displaying correctly.

JS script:

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%e-%b-%y %H:%M").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
.orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("#air_temp_chart")
.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("php/air_temperature_data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    }

    var tickValues = data.map(function(d) { return d.date; });

    xAxis
    .tickValues(tickValues)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

);

});
```

PHP data file:

```
$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$myquery = "SELECT  `date`, `close` FROM  `readings_air_temperature`";
$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}

$data = array();

for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);
```

?>

PHP output (JSON):

```
[{"date":"1-May-12 06:00","close":"58.13"},{"date":"1-May-12 06:30","close":"53.98"},{"date":"1-May-12 06:30","close":"88.00"},{"date":"1-May-12 06:30","close":"101.29"}]
```

The data file seems to be fine but the graph is not loading any data. Instead, the graph just shows the x and y axis without any labels or data.

When I look at the SVG output in Inspector in my browser, this is what I get:

```
<svg height="270" width="600"><g transform="translate(50,30)"><path class="line"></path><g transform="translate(0,210)" class="x axis"><path d="M0,6V0H530V6" class="domain"></path></g><g class="y axis"><path d="M-6,0H0V210H-6" class="domain"></path></g></g></svg>
```

Can someone point me to what is wrong?

Comment: Place this on top of your PHP data file. It might do the trick: header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I placed it as the first line but it didnt work :(

Comment: The live output of the graph can be seen at http://activetechnologies.us/garden . The graph in question is the "Air Temperature" graph which you will notice is blank. The other graphs are pulling data from csv files

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?  And where exactly are you decoding the encoded JSON - can you show us that part of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("php/air_temperature_data.php", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    }
     //... SHOULD BE IN HERE
);

// ALL THIS STUFF...
var tickValues = data.map(function(d) { return d.date; });

xAxis
.tickValues(tickValues)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%H:%M'));

// Scale the range of the data
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

// Add the valueline path.
svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

It's a sync issue. `data` will only be returned asynchronously within the d3.csv callback (the `function(error,data)` bit). The program however calls d3.csv and then continues on as if the data is available immediately. See the comments I added to your code ^^^

---

Edit2: It's a d3.csv call and we need d3.json as it's json getting returned!

Comment: I updated the code based on your suggestion. The axes populate however the intervals on the axes are not correct based on the data and the line itself is not displaying...

Comment: You can see the output of the graph at: http://activetechnologies.us/garden/

It is the "Air Temperature" graph

Comment: you've included everything in the callback, but a lot of it also within the .each loop. Everything below `d.close = +d.close;` shouldn't be in the loop. Move it out of that loop, but still in the callback.

Comment: in fact, all of it is the each loop, keep it into the callback, but move it out the loop, and move the last 2 svg appends in your code into the callback - they depend on xaxis and yaxis which depend on data so need to be in there

Comment: Thank you for the continued help! I updated the code per your instructions (please see my original post) but unfortunately it is still not working. In fact, all graphs are now breaking so there must be an error in the code?

Comment: simple bracket error I probably introduced for you :-) , see the changed answer ^^^

Comment: Ok I fixed that. The other graphs have returned to normal but the Air Temperature graph is still not populating :(.. blank axes

Comment: At this point I'd do a console.log ("error", error, "data", data); in the callback to see exactly what the php is throwing back

Comment: I apologize for being a noob.. where should I put the console.log line? inside the call itself?

Comment: Do it after the each loop in the callback so you see the data just before you try and do d3 things to it

Comment: Aaargh, think I may have spotted it, and it's utterly unrelated :-) You're returning json, but it's a d3.csv call you're using....

Comment: Ahh! You are exactly right! I completely missed that as well. Thank you so much for your diligence on this! Really appreciate the help.. probably would have taken me a lot longer to realize the error. Cheers